# Flash as3 Error 1180 that I don't understand

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So, I got an error 1180 message with the following code:

```
package objects.moving.dudes {
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import objects.moving.Moving;
    import misc.MoveTimer;
    public class Dude extends Moving {
        public function Dude() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageAddHandler);
        }
        public var theMoveTimer;
        public function stageAddHandler(e:Event) {
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageAddHandler);
        }
        public function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent) {
            theMoveTimer = new MoveTimer(e.keyCode);
        }
    }
}
```

It said, "call to a possibly undefined method MoveTimer".

Here is the class MoveTimer:

```
package misc {
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    class MoveTimer {
        private const TIMER_LENGTH = 500;
        public function MoveTimer(myKeyCode:int) {
            keyCode = myKeyCode;
        }
        public var keyCode:int;
        public var timer = new Timer(TIMER_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

I've looked at several different possible solutions to Error 1180, and none of them were applicable/worked for this one. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

EDIT: I made some mistakes while transferring my code to stackoverflow, and I have made changes to make it look more like my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution! And I feel so stupid, but I needed to add the word `public` to my `MoveTimer` class:

```
package misc {
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    public class MoveTimer { //This is the line where I added the word 'public'. See my question for the incorrect version of this line.
        private const TIMER_LENGTH = 500;
        public function MoveTimer(myKeyCode:int) {
            keyCode = myKeyCode;
        }
        public var keyCode:int;
        public var timer = new Timer(TIMER_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as i see you forgot to type your variable `theMoveTimer` as `MoveTimer` and the `MoveTimer` class isn't imported in your `Dude` class.
Try to change your declaration for `theMoveTimer` to:

```
public var theMoveTimer:MoveTimer;
```

and add the following line to your imports:

```
import misc.MoveTimer;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did a bad job of transferring my code. I tried to take out everything that wasn't pertinent to the question, and I forgot to add the import part that is in my original code (I actually did import MoveTimer in my original code). I've edited my question to contain the import statement. Also, if I type theMoveTimer like so: `public var theMoveTimer:MoveTimer;`, I still get the 1180, and I get a 1046 that says: "type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MoveTimer, citing the line `public var theMoveTimer:MoveTimer;` I'm super confused, because i don't understand the errors...

Answer (score 0):

I think the first line of your Dude class should start with 'package'. That, and the changes Binou suggests, ie: adding the MoveTimer type to your theMoveTimer declaration and importing the MoveTimer class in your Dude class.

Comment: Oh no, I did it again! My actual code contains the word public at the beginning; I just tried to simplify my code for stackoverflow and accidentally left out important parts. I'll edit it to reflect that.

Comment: Unless you know something I don't, you shouldn't start a class with 'public'. Classes should start with 'package'. Your class should then be saved in a folder structure (relative to where your .swf is being compiled) that corresponds to the path described after 'package'.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I did it again! I'm so sick of my incompetence at copying and pasting! But guess what, at first I misunderstood the comment you just made, and it helped me fix the problem, so thanks, you are a life-saver! Guess I'll edit my question one more time, to show what my problem is, and then I'll answer my question.